# Lagrange polynomial in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I Working on a code, where one can plug in the x and y values for the points you want to approximate with a Lagrange polynomial. I wrote "P = sum(L)" as I want it sum up the numbers in each column. But it gives me an error. Hope somebody knows whats wrong.

My code:

```
X = input('Enter list of x-values: ');
Y = input('Enter list of y-values: ');
n = length(X);
L = zeros(n,n);
for i=1:n
    V = 1
    for j=1:n
      if i~=j
         V = conv(V,poly(X(j)))/(X(i)-X(j))
      end
    end
    L(i,:) = V*Y(i);
end
L
P = sum(L)
```

When I plug in my x and y-values I get:

```
lagrangepoly
Enter list of x-values: [2;3;5]
Enter list of y-values: [5;7;8]

V =

     1


V =

    -1     3


V =

         0.333333333333333         -2.66666666666667                         5


V =

     1


V =

     1    -2


V =

                      -0.5                       3.5                        -5


V =

     1


V =

         0.333333333333333        -0.666666666666667


V =

         0.166666666666667        -0.833333333333333                         1


L =

          1.66666666666667         -13.3333333333333                        25
                      -3.5                      24.5                       -35
          1.33333333333333         -6.66666666666667                         8

Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in lagrangepoly (line 15)
P = sum(L)
```

So basically I want it to add the numbers in the columns I marked with green here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyS2h.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
X = input('Enter list of x-values: ');
Y = input('Enter list of y-values: ');
n = length(X);
sum = 0;
for i=1:n
    V = 1
    for j=1:n
        if i~=j
        V = conv(V,poly(X(j))/(X(i)-X(j));
        end
    end
    term = p*y(i);
    sum= sum + term;
end
disp(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you. But this does not give me the sum of each column. I should get: -0.5 , 4.5 and -2